# The short type in C#

Tags: c#

I am learning value types in C# and I noticed this:

when you hover over the value of a declared short, It says that It is a 32-bit int.
I know that a short is a 16-bit int.
Why isn't It recognizing It as an int, or maybe It does?

[image]

Comment: That value there (32000) is still an int

Comment: hover over the variable name

Comment: Why is it still an int?

Comment: Please read the docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals, in particular, "If the determined type of an integer literal is int and the value represented by the literal is within the range of the destination type, the value can be implicitly converted to [the destination type]"

Comment: Literals all have types: `1.2` (and `1.2d`) is a `double`, `1.2f` is a `float`, `1.2m` is a `decimal`, `32000u` is a `uint`, and `32000` is an `int`, etc. When you assign a literal to a variable of a different type then the compiler does the conversion (if possible) for you - either at compile-time or run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are hovering over the value (32000) which is an `int`/`System.Int32` literal. There isn't a suffix for short to make a literal short. The compiler will do some gymnastics to ensure that it will fit. For instance, this should not compile.

```
int max = int.MaxValue;
short aShort = max;
```

Comment: Okay Thank you, then why is there the value type short? Why does it exist?

Comment: This doesn't compile either, even though the value *does* fit: `int anInt = 42; short aShort = anInt;`  Perhaps you meant to have `const int max` ?

Comment: Thank you, so why do we have the type Short then, if after initialization, it still is an int(the short)?

Comment: @EricMovsessian: It's not a 32-bit int *after* initialization.  By hovering, you're looking at the value that goes *into* initialization, not the value that comes out.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: So does that mean that the 32000 is  a short after all?

Comment: @EricMovsessian: In `short uw = 32000;` you have an integer literal, and a `short` variable.  The variable absolutely "is a `short`".  If you read that variable later, you will get 32000 and it has type short.  However, the integer literal `32000` also has a data type, different from the variable you are storing it into.  The `int` data type of the literal means that if you use the literal directly in a function call like `BitConverter.GetBytes(32000)`, the `BitConverter.GetBytes(Int32)` function gets called and not the `BitConverter.GetBytes(Int16)`.  So `32000` "is an `int`"

Answer (score 2):

You should try to separate the declaration from the assignment of values

```
+-- declare      +-- assign
|                |
short uwuhebfuyg = 3200;
```

Note that the declaration should be able to stand on its own, as the following is valid code

```
short uwuhebfuyg;
```

which could be assigned a value zero, one or more times later in code.

```
uwuhebfuyg = 100;
uwuhebfuyg = 16383;
```

Here the compiler interprets the digits as an integer and tries to fit it inside a short data type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explicit example of what's happening with the implicit conversion you're asking about.

Try this `struct`:

```
public struct NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString
{
    public string Value;
    public NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString(string source)
    {
        this.Value = source.Length <=2 ? source : source.Substring(0, 2);
    }

    public static implicit operator NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString(string source)
        => new NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString(source);
}
```

It defines a struct that holds a string that must not be longer than 2 characters. It defines an `implicit operator` than will allow any `string` to be assigned to a variable of type `NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString`.

You could use this type like this:

```
NoMoreThanTwoCharacterString x = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
```

That writes out `He` to the console.

The type on the left of the `=` can be different to the type on the right. The `implicit operator` allows for the assignment to work, but in doing so it may need change the incoming value.